# Is there a way to detect the provider of a Git repository based on the information available in a repo clone?

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

How can I detect what Git provider is available behind a certain "remote" (I can see it in the `.git/config`). I am talking here about on-premise installed Git servers where the domain names are not explicit enough (like git.company.com).

I want to know if I am working with a Gitlab or a Bitbucket server for example. The two products having different ways they work and different APIs. I would like to know for example which API to load when working with a certain Git repo. Or how to parse some commit messages that each Git provider generated differently.

Comment: You can inspect the URL itself: if it ends with `github.com` it's clearly hosted on GitHub, for instance. This fails in a lot of cases, and if you have one of those cases, there's no fixed right answer. You could set up your own mapping table, or you could probe for APIs at the URL.

Comment: @torek "*on-premise installed Git servers where the domain names are not explicit enough*"

Comment: @phd: yeah, those are what I was referring to when I said "this fails in a lot of cases". :-) Admittedly it's right there in the question too...

Answer (score 3):

Based solely on the information in a repo clone, no, you can't.  However, there are ways you can query the remote server to see what it might support.

For example, you could try the REST API endpoint for each server type and see what kind of response you get.  You can also query the SSH endpoint for each server; the server version string will contain "babeld" for GitHub Enterprise, an OpenSSH string for GitLab, and usually something Java-based for Bitbucket Server.

There are also distinctive HTTP headers for some servers.  You can tack on `/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack` to the end of the URL (which is the refs endpoint).  GitHub will provide you a server header with `GitHub Babel`, GitLab may provide you with special `GitLab` headers, and Bitbucket may also provide identifiable headers (such as `x-server`).

In general, though, you can't parse commit messages based on the remote server type, since a particular project may have moved from one to another.  That happens at various companies all the time, and for open source projects, too.

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution. Unfortunately, in our cases, no SSH ports are opened towards these endpoints.

Comment: I've offered some additional HTTP headers that may be distinctive.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

From the `git` point of view there is no any API, only Git Protocol and all servers implement the protocol in (almost) the same way.

If you want to use server-specific API it's completely outside of `git` knowledge. You have to know what is the server and what version of API it implements. Or probe for known API endpoints and protocols.